# PHP doesn't receive $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a problem with my PHP, I'm doing an ajax post with jquery.
The problem: my PHP doesnt receive any POST, with GET there are no problems.
I'm using the last jquery version.
Ajax doesnt throw any error, I tried with error:function(...) and console.log.

idCat is a number, for example: 3
$nuevaFila and other undeclared variables are previously declared, they aren't constructive.

PHP returns well the HTML because I try any html and I receive it ok

The ajax code is this one:

```
$.ajax({
    cache:false,
    type:'post',
    url:'admin/categoria_ajax_ad',
    data: {id: idCat},
    success: function(htmlFila) {       
        var nFila=$cFilas.find(".fila").size()+1;
        $nuevaFila.html(htmlFila);
        $nuevaFila.appendTo($cFilas);
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you inspect the request with dev tools (in FF, Chrome, Safari, etc.)? Does the request ever get sent?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Make sure idCat is set and the url is correct.

Comment: What do you receive in `$nuevaFila`?

Comment: The URL is correct, because if I write in the PHP echo 'blablabla' I receive it.

Comment: So if you `alert(idCat)` just before `$.ajax` what do you see?

Comment: I would think about setting the data-types and encoding. really you should provide us with a bit more information about what data format PHP is returning - you should be encoding into XML or JSON (usually)

Comment: I said, id is an integer example: idCat=23542

Comment: I'm returning HTML with the PHP and the javascript function receive it well, the problem is that PHP receives POST and not GET

Comment: Also what version of jquery are you using? For my tests I used `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Woah wait, `PHP doesnt receive any POST` and `PHP receives POST and not GET` -- I'm confused

Comment: If you want get, just put a `?idCat=23542` at the end of the url. Post should work fine, and if you append it with the example, then both post and get will work.

Comment: I'm using the latest jquery version

Answer (score 0):

Try using **dataType (xml, json, script, or html)**  setting parameter like this depending on your return data type -

```
$.ajax({
cache:false,
type:'post',
url:'admin/categoria_ajax_ad',
data: {id: idCat},
dataType : "string"
success: function(htmlFila) {       
    var nFila=$cFilas.find(".fila").size()+1;
    $nuevaFila.html(htmlFila);
    $nuevaFila.appendTo($cFilas);
    },
});
```

Comment: There's no problem with the ajax function, if I change type:post for type:get it works, the problem isn't that

Comment: dataType is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server, if none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response. And sometime it fails to infer and returns null.